# Hide parent nodes in Xtext Outline View

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm working on an Xtext parser, and have run into an issue: With the IDE plugin for Eclipse, specifically the *Outline* view, it tends to show `<unnamed>` nodes, which I don't want to display.

Currently, the nodes are as so:

- SourceFile (simply the name of the file that I'm currently using)

  - TopLevelStatement

    - Declare

      - StructDeclaration

        - StructCreator

          - `name=Identifier` - Same identifier as below.
      - ClassDeclaration

        - ClassCreator

          - `name=Identifier` - Same identifier as below.
    - Identifier

      - ID (the `terminal` that comes with Xtext)

With all the mess above, if I do something such as:

```
class TestClass {}
struct TestStruct {}
```

I would expect:

- SourceFile

  - TestClass
  - TestStruct

But what I *really* get, is this:

- SourceFile

  - `<unnamed>`

    - `<unnamed>`

      - `<unnamed>`

        - `<unnamed>`

          - TestClass
  - `<unnamed>`

    - `<unnamed>`

      - `<unnamed>`

        - `<unnamed>`

          - TestStruct

I really just want to hide **every** `<unnamed>` node in my Xtext project, as it would be beneficial to every case where I don't want something to appear, however if not possible, I simply want the specific nodes above to be hidden. I've tried the documentation, but can't seem to find any information as towards hiding a specific node, **especially when it has multiple types of children**.

Here is my grammar code:

```
SourceFile:
    (statements+=TopLevelStatement)*
;

TopLevelStatement:
    statement=(Declaration)
;

Declaration:
    declare=(StructDeclaration|ClassDeclaration)
;

StructDeclaration:
    declare=StructCreator '{' '}' ';'?
;

ClassDeclaration:
    declare=ClassCreator '{' '}' ';'?
;

StructCreator:
    'struct' id=Identifier
;

ClassCreator:
    'class' id=Identifier
;

Identifier:
    ID
;
```

You may look at the above code and ask why I don't merge the class and struct creators into one, but I **can't**. I'm going to have a few more rules for both the class and struct, which I haven't added, as they don't contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place i dont understand this wired object structure you create. is there any reason to do this the way you do it?

Step one: implement label provider

```
class MyDslLabelProvider extends DefaultEObjectLabelProvider {

    @Inject
    new(AdapterFactoryLabelProvider delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }
    // xtext does reflective polymorphic dispatch on params
    def text(StructCreator ele) {
        ele.id
    }

    def text(ClassCreator ele) {
        ele.id
    }

}
```

Step two: Implement Outline Tree Provider

```
class MyDslOutlineTreeProvider extends DefaultOutlineTreeProvider {

    // xtext does reflective polymorphic dispatch on params
    def protected _createChildren(IOutlineNode parentNode, SourceFile modelElement) {
            for (s : modelElement.statements) {
                val firstDecl = s.statement?.declare
                if (firstDecl instanceof StructDeclaration) {
                    val secondDecl = firstDecl.declare
                    if (secondDecl !== null) {
                        createNode(parentNode, secondDecl)
                    }
                } else if (firstDecl instanceof ClassDeclaration) {
                    val secondDecl = firstDecl.declare
                    if (secondDecl !== null) {
                        createNode(parentNode, secondDecl)
                    }
                }

            }
    }

}
```

Alternative 0: Change Grammar and Naming Conventions

```
SourceFile:
    (statements+=TopLevelStatement)*
;

TopLevelStatement:
    Declaration
;

Declaration:
    StructDeclaration|ClassDeclaration
;

StructDeclaration:
    'struct' name=Identifier '{' '}' ';'?
;

ClassDeclaration:
    'class' name=Identifier '{' '}' ';'?
;

Identifier:
    ID
;
```

Comment: I've done it so 'wired-like', because I'm also going to use non `{ and }` tokens, replacing them with semicolons. Theres a whole branch pattern missing not related to the issue. I just decided to disclude them as they don't contribute and make it look more messy than it is.

Comment: And Christian is at it once again. Thankyou! You've become my guiding light. :)

Comment: Christian, I was just wondering, is there a simple way to simply move a node from one parent, to that of a complete other? I'm fine to ask another question and have someone answer it, but you have the correct answers for everything!

Comment: well have a look what the outline tree provider does. there you are actually contructing the tree. => you need to implement it there